# Configuring a macbook for a specific case

Tags: macos, configuration

I've used cleanbrowsing.org as a DNS filter, created an administrator account, logged in into that account, changed my usual (admin) account to a normal user and set the new admin account with a long password that I can't remember (copy paste password). This should be a measure to clean my browsing results and if I'm inattentive It should not be easy to circumvent it, but that's not the case, in fact, I can easily boot into Single User Mode, change the root password, log in as root and I can do whatever I want again. What are some things I should do to restrict my whole Macbook in the worst and most effective way possible without I being able to circumvent it?

Here are some things I already have:

- Chromium set up with a plugin policy (to avoid Proxy usage).
- CleanBrowsing DNS
- Another admin account functioning as parenting account who's password has been intentionally forgotten.

Comment: Although you cannot outsmart yourself, I'm only trying to make it as hard as possible or it need so much work to bypass all controls, that I give up.

Comment: not use mac os x? but a os like tails! from a usb stick...